# Как сделать внутри Android приложения папку с файлами и как работать с ней

Tags: android, файлы, context

Нужно поставлять с приложением некоторый набор файлов. В уроках и документации, всё и ничего толком. Мне не нужно иметь возможность искать файлы по всему телефону, к тому же мне не нужны эти Assets, я хочу получать файл по его имени.

Вроде нашел нечто похожее - getContext().getFilesDir(). Но я так и не понял, куда нужно положить файлы  в проекте, чтобы увидеть их этим выражением.

Comment: по `getContext().getFilesDir()` вы получаете папку приложения в `/data/data/_приложение_` - без рута вы во вторую `data` не войдете.

Comment: А есть ли возможность сделать так, чтобы после компиляции там появились какие то файлы? По факту читать и сохранять нужно через приложение, пользователю эти файлы как файлы вообще ни к чему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если файлы нужно распространять с приложением, то это только через Asset.

Дальше просто при первом запуске копируйте их в папку, которую возвращает метод
   `getContext().getFilesDir()`, и дальше работать с методами, которые предоставляет `Context`.
Сделать так, что бы файлы после установки сразу автоматически появлялись во внутренней папке приложения нельзя.

Comment: Замечу, что копировать файлы куда-либо - совсем не обязательно. Файлы могут быть большие, а места на внутренней флешке и без того мало. Кроме того, некоторые умудряются делать копирование при каждом запуске приложения, что дико тормозит запуск.